# cloud run logs show scanned <tens of gigs>

Tags: google-cloud-run

[image: screenshot]

I have a simple service running that doesn't log at all. The logs view shows currently 31.1gb of logs and is growing fast. What's going on?

Comment: What is the activity on your service? Can you tell me the avg request per minute or second?

Comment: avg request second is 0. also logs don't show anything.

Comment: this happens with any account and service, just try it

Comment: I'm seeing this too, and I only just created the Google cloud account and project today. Created a single function and checked the logs, scanned up to 23 GB before I clicked away. Really hope there is no billing associated with that!

Answer (score 0):

This number represents the size of all logs for all services across your project. The Cloud Run logging page is scanning all logs and filtering for logs from the Cloud Run resource.

Comment: I created a brand new Google cloud account and a single function, and it already showed scanning up to 23 GB without even executing it. My new account surely hasn't generated that many logs already.